# Uploading a project to GitHub using the command line

Tags: git, github

How do I upload a project to GitHub through the command line? I have installed Git on Windows. I am uploading my project by creating a new repository, but it did not upload by command line.

Comment: You probably want something like `git push -u origin master` ... check the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step-1:**

Download git from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

**Step-2:**

Create a repository in [github](https://github.com/)

**Step-3:**

goto your project folder

**step-4**

open git bash or cmd and initialize your project by typing `git init`

**step-5**

add files by typing `git add .` for adding all file

**step-6**

commit your project by typing `git commit -m 'your message'`

**step-7**

copy your remote location from github by typing

```
git remote add origin 'your repository link'
```

**step-8**

push your code in github by typing `git push -u origin master`

and thats all you need to do. Or check github [documentation.](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)

Comment: when i am typing git add . it did not upload any folder or not giving me option to upload files.

Comment: the folder is hidden and `git add .` is not for uploading folder.
Its just add your project in git directory.

You have yo do `step-7` and `step-8` for upload files in Github server.

Answer (score 2):

**How do I upload a project on GitHub?**

1. Create a repository in GitHub
2. Open Git Bash
3. Select the repository directory (`cd <path to folder>`)
4. Run the following commands.

   ```
   git init
   git remote add origin <repository clone link>
   git add .
   git commit -m "commit"
   git push origin master
   ```
5. Reload your GitHub repository page …
6. Now your project will upload successfully.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.