# How to upload my project to github from my computer. I have a project created which is loacted on Desktop

Tags: git, github

```
$ git config --global user.name.
$ git config --global user.email
$ git config --global color.ui auto
$ cd path/to/project/folder
$ git init
$ ls -la
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

What next?
my project folder path is as follows:
/home/parichay/Desktop
The project folder lied within the Desktop. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Please help me.My project is developed in VS code editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading a project to GitHub using the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485297/uploading-a-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Please close question by accepting any answer or ask for clarifications if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Git Bash
Change the current working directory to your local project.
Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.

```
git init
```

Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first commit.

```
git add .
```

Commit the files that you’ve staged in your local repository.

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Copy the https url of your newly created repo
In the Command prompt, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL

git remote -v
```

Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.

```
git push -f origin master
```

Finally, this has been answered already,

[Uploading a project to GitHub using the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48485297/uploading-a-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Okay I got the, steps, just for more clarification, do I need to put the path as :
/home/parichay/Desktop/projectFoldername in place of the remote repository URL?

Comment: @ParichayPari Noooo, Thanks for asking. It is git url. Go to your git account and create repository. Copy that url and paste here. eg: github.com/username/repname.git

Comment: Thanks a lot, for clarifying this.

Comment: Cool, I guess you can accept answer now. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please help me one more issue, How do I change the name of the repository in github. As I'm not getting any option to do so.

Comment: Instead use a different name for the new repository and delete that old one. Renaming breaks code requests

Answer (score 0):

I would just add, create a Github repository without any content like `.gitignore`, license, `README`, etc., so there're no commits, otherwise you won't be able to easily push your changes into the repository.

The reason is that both the local and the remote repository will already have its own tree of commits and a `master` branch.

If you have a remote repository with any commits already, you should clone that repository locally first and then commit your work there.